# How to prevent std::string being constructed from a nullptr at build time by checking the optimized compiler output

Tags: c++, stl, nullptr

GCC doesn't output a warning when it's optimizer detects std::string being compiled with a nullptr. I found a workaround, just wondering if anything better. It takes advantage of the std::string implementation having an assert that fires when constructed with nullptr. So by compiling with optimisation and looking at the assembly, I can see that line.

Note, below is just an example, this isn't application code.
However, I wondered if there is a better way than what I do.  I search for __throw_logic_error with that particular string.

I've pasted this from godbolt.org.
Can be compiled with GCC 12 as follows:

```
g++ -O1 -S -fverbose-asm -std=c++23 -Wall -o string.s string.cpp

#include <string>
void f()
{
    const char * a = nullptr;
    std::string s(a);
}

int main()
{
   f();
}




.LC0:
        .string "basic_string: construction from null is not valid"
f():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    f()
```

Comment: why this particular nullptr usage and not others (delete nullptr, file open with nullname,...). Sounds like you should use a static code analyzer like pvs studio etc

Comment: I tried with all the possible gcc warnings active an none of the detected this problem. Static analysis is the only other option. Feel lucky that it give a sensible message. By the way, on second though you probably can't do anything about it because throwing an exception (even a logical one) is considered valid code. This is when you wish the standard has defined this situation as undefined behavior rather than baby sitting many possible failures.

Comment: Thank you for the clang-tidy suggestion. Your post seems to have a disappeared, but thank you. Just sharing the link again. https://godbolt.org/z/zorrPK99n

Comment: Just to add, c++20 does not detect at compile time std::string(NULL), std::string(nullptr) and std::string(0) but fortunately c++23 does with GCC 12. <source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:10:23: error: use of deleted function

Comment: @pm100 -- `delete nullptr` works just fine. It has no effect.

Comment: @pm100 GCC 12.2 gives a clear error "<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:16:5: error: type 'std::nullptr_t' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
   16 |     delete nullptr;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1"

Comment: PVS-Studio: V522 Dereferencing of the null pointer 'a' might take place. A constructor of the '__cxx11::basic_string' class expects a valid pointer. https://godbolt.org/z/1xEddEYxo

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception could be in principle a legal use.
(This is the problem with `logic_error`'s, they shouldn't be exceptions.)

For this reason, I doubt that a compiler will ever complain about this, even if it can evaluate all at compile time.
Your best bet is a static analyzer.

The version of clang-tidy in godbolt, can detect this,

```
warning: The parameter must not be null [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.StringChecker]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h9GnT9ojx

This was incorporated in clang-tidy 17, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/checkers.html#cplusplus-stringchecker-c

---

In the lines of compiler warnings you could be lucky (eventually) with something like this, although I wasn't lucky.

```
void f() {
    const char * a = nullptr;
    try {
        std::string s(a);
    }catch(std::logic_error&) {
        std::unreacheable();  // or equivalent for current GCC
    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you for sharing. I wish GCC would catch up and add this.  Static analysis is good, much better than relying on runtime checks and asserts etc. You're right the standard library has a lucky bit of text there to search for, after that logic_error

Comment: @rich, There is some procedural static analysis in GCC, so I would have guessed that GCC could catch these through one or more of these: `-Wanalyzer-null-argument -Wanalyzer-possible-null-argument -Wanalyzer-null-dereference -Wanalyzer-possible-null-dereference`, but I it didn't work. https://godbolt.org/z/9scM6xfPY

Comment: @rich Nothing prevents you from using GCC to compile and clang-tidy to analyze the code.

Comment: See here for static analysis in GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html

Comment: thank you again for the GCC static analyzer suggestions. I added them to the build, but they don't catch this one unfortunately.

Comment: For them to become active you need `-fanalyzer` before them. GCC gives a lot of false positives though.